# How to use Rails and SASS to generate a stylesheet that only contains specific rules

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, asset-pipeline

I've looked around for someone else trying to do something like that, but I haven't been able to find it. Here goes:

I have a CMS where users are able to select HEX color values for six specific colors. They're saved in the db (like `site.color_1` for example). The problem is, I can't pull these DB colors into my sass file. The best I can do is create a .css.erb file, copy over every rule from the precompiled css, and replace all instances of `#555` with `<%= site.color_1 %>`.

Ideally though, I'd like sass/rails to look out for any rule that contains `#555` and spit that rule out in a separate stylesheet. For bonus points, it would automatically replace `#555` with `<%= site.color_1 %>`. I've never heard of such a thing, but if it's possible, that would automate this whole nightmarish process.

If this kind of thing doesn't exist, is it even something that's theoretically possible for a gem working with the rails asset pipeline to pull off?

I'm on the latest rails and sass-rails gems.

Comment: I'm a little unclear about what exactly your goal is, but it sounds like you could use [SCSS variables](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/#variables) for that? Create a `.scss.erb` file, define the variables there, e.g. `$color1: <%= site.color_1 %>` and only reference `$color1` in the rest of your stylesheets.

Comment: That would work if the `.scss.erb` file compiles into a `.css.erb` file, and preserves the rails block, but I didn't think it did that. If it does this is a solved problem. I'll check it out now.

Comment: If you want to use SCSS variables, it cannot be compiled to CSS. Instead, you need to use SCSS import directives to include them in your other files (and they need to be `css.scss.erb` files as well for that to work): `@import 'variables';`

Comment: I've got `_colors.css.scss.erb` which looks like this: `$link-default: <%= @color_test %>;` but when I `@import` that into my SCSS file, it just throws a SASS syntax error: `Sass::SyntaxError ... Invalid CSS after "$color1: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"`

Comment: It has to be just `_colors.scss.erb` - compiling it to CSS wouldn't do any good if it only contains SCSS variables. In CSS, it's just an empty file.

Comment: That probably means that `@color_test`  is nil. Where'd you try to define it? Assets are not parsed in your view context, so you do not have access to variables you set in your controller action.

Comment: I've got the current pgae controller set up with `@color_test = 'green'`. `$color1: <%= @color_test || 'black' %>;` works and renders black, but if I take out the `|| 'black'` then it throws the same error, probably like you said because it's evaluating to nil.

Comment: One more note, I only got this working up to this point because I added `'*.css.erb'` to my config.assets.precompile array in the development.rb env file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71321/discussion-between-cranderveldt-and-janfoeh).